# How to Remove Default Padding for sap.m.ObjectHeader Without CSS

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to use [ObjectHeader](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ObjectHeader) but it has standard padding given by `.sapMOH` style class. I want to remove that padding.

I tried:

- `<ObjectHeader class="sapUiNoContentPadding" binding="" title="text">`
- `class="sapUiSizeCompact"`
- `.removeStyleClass("sapMOH");`

But none of the above seems to work.

How to achieve it without custom CSS?

Comment: There seems to be no way currently to remove the default padding without custom CSS. May I ask why you want to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to add a CSS file, you could try to directly add the style to the HTML description of the element. In this case that would be along the lines of (depending on whether you use HTML/XML/JS views):

```
<ObjectHeader style="padding:0px !important" class="sapUiNoContentPadding" binding="" title="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a way to achieve this without custom css so please, if anyone knows, let us know...

In the meantime, I decided to implement the "expected" behavior by myself which gives me something like this :

**CSS:**

```
/* sapMOH stands for ObjectHeader */
.sapUiNoContentPadding > .sapMOH {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Then simply apply the class on your `ObjectHeader` like you would have expected.

**XML:**

```
<ObjectHeader
class="sapUiNoContentPadding"
...
>
    ...
</ObjectHeader>
```

This solution is correct using **sapui5 1.113.0 version**.